CORS on AWS with LAMBDA python rest serverless
I have set up everything for the project enviorment (RDS db, S3 + Cloudfront for client side and AWS Lambda python in the backend.
Ive also set cors configuration in the server code for the flask app.
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": URL}}, supports_credentials=True)

and in API Gateway I created get, post, put, delete and set CORS for them.
on the clien I am getting:

Access to fetch at [API SERVER URL] from origin [CLIENT URL] has been
blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass
access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Anyone knows what have I missed?

You need to allow cors in API gateway console. Aws Docs.
And then you need to Deploy the api.

Knowing that you're using flask in lambda i expect that the gateway route is /{proxy+}. In this case is also necessary to create a OPTIONS handler for all routes paths to allow preflight. Here's why. See related solution for options response. But basically is this:
@app.route("/", methods=["OPTIONS"])
def my_preflight_cors():
    resp = flask.Response("")
    resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    return resp


No, I am not using a proxy resource

@NoamAzoulay then just adding cors and deploying like in the image must work.
